# Display content and its related contents in Perl/Mysql

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to achieve this sample output from a small Perl project like this

```
   content1
        relatedcontent1
        relatedcontent2
        relatedcontent2
   content2
        relatedcontent1
        relatedcontent2
```

here is my code

```
   #!C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use v5.10; # for say() function
   use DBI;
   use HTML::Table;

   # MySQL database configurations
   my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:naxum";
   my $username = "root";
   my $password = '';
   print "Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   # connect to MySQL database
   my %attr = ( PrintError=>0,  # turn off error reporting via warn()
         RaiseError=>1   # report error via die()
       );
   my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,$username,$password,\%attr);

   # query data from the sponsor table
   query_sponsor($dbh);
   query_person_by_target($dbh);

   sub query_sponsor{
   # query from the  table
    my ($dbh) = @_;
    my $sql = "SELECT name,id FROM sponsor";
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    # execute the query
   $sth->execute();
   print "<table>\n";
   print "<thead>\n";
   print "<tr>\n";
   print "<th>Id</th>\n";
   print "<th>Name</th>\n";
   print "</tr>\n";
   print "</thead>\n";
   print "<tbody>\n";
   while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()){

 print "<tr>\n";
 print "<td>\n";
 print $row['1'];

  sub query_person_by_target{
      my ($dbhPerson) = @_;
      my $sqlPerson = "SELECT username, firstname FROM person WHERE sponsor_id = ?";
      my $sthPerson = $dbhPerson->prepare($sqlPerson);
     $sthPerson->execute($row['1']) or die "execution failed: $dbhPerson->errstr()";
      while ( my @rowPerson = $sthPerson->fetchrow_array()){
          print "<p>$rowPerson['0']</p>\n";
      }
      $sth->finish();
 }
 print "</td>\n";
 print "<td>$row['0']</td>\n";
 print "</tr>\n";
 }
 $sth->finish();
 print "</tbody>\n";
 print "</table>\n";
 }
 $dbh->disconnect();
```

However, I can't  get the output what I am trying to achieve. Here is the result

```
   content1
   content2
   content3
   .....
   relatedcontent1
```

It will just print one related content outside contents. Every content and its own at least 3 relatedcontent each.

Answer (score 0):

You define your subroutines in the middle of other code in your program. This makes me think you expect them to be executed as they are defined, but that's not the case - they are executed as you call them. And you call them like this:

```
query_sponsor($dbh);
query_person_by_target($dbh);
```

So it should come as no surprise that you get all of the output from `query_sponsor()` followed by all of the output from `query_person_by_name()`.

A far better approach would be to call `query_person_by_target()` from within `query_sponsor()`. I'd also split this into two phases - phase one to extract the data into a data structure and phase two to display that data.

As I don't have your database, this code is untested.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'state'; # for state variables
use feature 'say';
use CGI 'header';

sub get_dbh {
  # MySQL database configurations
  my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:naxum";
  my $username = "root";
  my $password = '';
  # connect to MySQL database
  my %attr = (
    PrintError=>0,  # turn off error reporting via warn()
    RaiseError=>1,  # report error via die()
  );

  return DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password, \%attr);
}

sub query_sponsor {
  state $dbh = get_dbh();

  my $sql = 'select name, id from sponsor';
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute;

  my @sponsors;

  while (my @row = $dbh->fetchrow_array) {
    push @sponsors, {
      name   => $row[0],
      id     => $row[1],
      people => get_people_for_sponsor($row[1]),
    };
  }

  return @sponsors;
}

sub get_people_for_sponsor {
  my ($sponsor_id) = @_;

  state $dbh = get_dbh;

  my $sql = 'select username, firstname
             from   person
             where  sponsor_id = ?';
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare;
  $sth->execute($sponsor_id);
  my @people;
  while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    push @people, {
      username  => $row[0],
      firstname => $row[1],
    };
  }

  return \@people;
}

my @sponsors = query_sponsor();

# Now you have all of your data in @sponsors. You simply need
# to walk that array and use the data to build the output you
# want. My example is plain text - it shouldn't be too hard to
# convert it to HTML.

print header('text/plain');

for my $s (@sponsors) {
  say "$s->{id}: $s->{name}";
  for my $p (@{$s->{people}}) {
    say "* $p->{firstname} / $p->{username}";
  }
}
```

I'd also recommend that you look at using something like the Template Toolkit to produce your output. Putting raw HTML into your Perl program is a terrible idea - it is guaranteed to turn into an unmaintainable mess :-)

Answer (score -1):

You have declared the two subroutines and you are calling one after one so it is executing like that for example consider the following one

```
sub1();
sub2();

sub sub1()
{
    for(0..5)
    {
        print "hello\n";
        sub sub2()
        {
            print "hi\n";

        }
    }
}

#output
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hi
```

So you should remove the child `query_person_by_target` subroutine or call the child subroutine inside the parent subroutine `query_sponsor`  and declare the child subroutine outside of the sub and loop, like below (not tested)

```
query_sponsor($dbh);

sub query_sponsor
{
    # query from the  table
    my ($dbh) = @_;
    my $sql = "SELECT name,id FROM sponsor";
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    # execute the query
    $sth->execute();
    print "<table>\n";
    print "<thead>\n";
    print "<tr>\n";
    print "<th>Id</th>\n";
    print "<th>Name</th>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
    print "</thead>\n";
    print "<tbody>\n";
    while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array())
    {

        print "<tr>\n";
        print "<td>\n";
        print $row['1'];

        query_person_by_target($dbh);

        print "</td>\n";
        print "<td>$row['0']</td>\n";
        print "</tr>\n";
    }
    $sth->finish();
    print "</tbody>\n";
    print "</table>\n";
}

sub query_person_by_target{
    my ($dbhPerson) = @_;
    my $sqlPerson = "SELECT username, firstname FROM person WHERE sponsor_id = ?";
    my $sthPerson = $dbhPerson->prepare($sqlPerson);
    $sthPerson->execute($row['1']) or die "execution failed: $dbhPerson->errstr()";
    while ( my @rowPerson = $sthPerson->fetchrow_array()){
        print "<p>$rowPerson['0']</p>\n";
    }
    $sth->finish();
}
$dbh->disconnect();
```